# maven with spring mvc

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, maven

Anybody who have a web project  in maven with spring?
I don't know why I can't get my project working, therefore I need to see a working project to understand it.
A project with a simple login/logout in maven using spring mvc.

Tanks

I get a HTTP 404 when I run the project on server and I don't know what can be wrong.
Maybe something is wrong with som of my xml-files:

web.xml

```
  <persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns  /persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
         version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="bokingguard" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
       <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
       <!-- Entities -->
       <properties>
          <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
          <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/book"/>
          <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value=""/>
          <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="" />
          <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
          <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
          <property name="show_sql" value="true" />
        </properties>      
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

spring-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252"?>
   <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">

<!-- Use @Component annotations for bean definitions -->
<context:component-scan base-package="se.guard.domain" />
<context:component-scan base-package="se.guard.repository" />
<context:component-scan base-package="se.guard.service" />
<context:component-scan base-package="se.guard.controller" />

<!-- Use @Controller annotations for MVC controller definitions -->
<mvc:annotation-driven />

<!-- Add JPA support -->
<bean id="emf"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="loadTimeWeaver">
        <bean
class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver" />
    </property>
</bean>
<!-- Add Transaction support -->
<bean id="myTxManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="emf" />
</bean>
<!-- Use @Transaction annotations for managing transactions -->
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="myTxManager" />
<!-- View resolver -->
<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: You should post any errors that you're encountering so we can help you better.  This is a very vague question.

Comment: Which version of spring?  Also login/logout implies you need spring security.

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/ I think it can give you all you need :) good luck ！

Comment: and spring-service.xml <beans ......"> <bean id="userRepository"  class="se.guard.service.UserService" /> </bean>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Spring [PetClinic](http://static.springsource.org/docs/petclinic.html) or Maven [archetypes](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Archetypes+List) to ge a working application with Spring MVC

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the spring configuration in your web.xml. Do not forget to add spring configurations. eg.:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath*:META-INF/spring/applicationContext*.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
...
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>YourServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>WEB-INF/spring/webmvc-config.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>YourServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
...
```

BTW, in [STS](http://www.springsource.com/developer/sts) (Springsource Tool Suite) you have an interesting option: File>New>Project>Springsource Tool Suite>Spring Template Project. Then choose Spring MVC project and you will be given a HelloWorld project using Maven and Spring MVC.

Also, as Samarth pointed, Spring Roo is cool for Spring app bootstrapping.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Spring Roo](http://www.springsource.org/spring-roo) to generate Spring recommended project structure that uses maven and has the right dependencies automatically configured.
You can use it to integrate with Spring Security as well for login & logout.